# how to write linq query with join on 3 tables performing sum and multiplication

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, .net-core, sql-to-linq-conversion

How can i write a query in linq c#(EF Core 6) for total price and also map other fields of DTO along with total price.

sql Query:

```
SELECT (sum(c.ExtraPrice) + (a.PricePerSqM*10)) as TotalPrice FROM dbo.Cities a
JOIN dbo.CityExtras b ON a.CityId = b.CityId
JOIN dbo.Extras c ON b.ExtrasId = c.ExtrasId
where a.CityId = 1
group by PricePerSqM
```

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query:

```cs
var query = 
    from a in ctx.Cities
    from b in a.CityExtras
    where a.CityId == 1
    group new { a, b } by new { a.PricePerSqM } into g
    select new 
    {
        g.Key.PricePerSqM,
        TotalPrice = g.Sum(x => x.b.ExtraPrice) + g.Key.PricePerSqM * 10
    };
```

Comment: can you please guide in this query syntax how can we add contains() in where clause? e.g .Where(x => extraIds.Contains(x.ExtrasId) && x.CityId == 1)   extraIds is an integer list.

Comment: `where a.CityId == 1 && extraIds.Contains(b.ExtrasId)`

Comment: ´   public class QuotationDTO
    {
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int PricePerSqM { get; set; }
        public List<string>? Extras { get; set; }
        public List<int>? ExtraPrice { get; set; }
        public int Totalprice { get; set; }


    }´ can you please help to fill this DTO from the query , I am trying but ExtraPrice int is not going to the list.

Comment: Better update question

Comment: I have updated the question, please have a look.